# Continue working on the folders managed by vcs git after upgrading operating system

Tags: git

Our institution's desktop team has upgraded from RedHat 6 to 7 on my machine. It is actually a fresh installation of RedHat 7 in the system where Red Hat 6 was running.

I had backed up all my projects into the network storage before this upgrade. When the machine is ready under Red Hat 7, I cannot continue using git under the folders of my projects. If I run `git status`, I am getting the following error:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /scratch)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).`

A few uncommitted work is under such projects which I need to continue working on them rather than clone a new repository from the remote one. If I run `git init`, it definitely gets rid of all history.

Do you know how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Do you still see a `.git` folder in your project? Is it possible that you missed this folder when copying to the network share? I'm asking since the `.git` folder is "hidden" and as such might have been missed in the backup.

Comment: It sounds right what I thought. I ran ```rsync --ACavzhe``` command. Did this omit ```.git``` folder?

Comment: I'm not familiar with rsync - you'd be able to answer this question though since you're looking at the folders :) If the `.git` folder is not there, then yes, it did omit that folder.

Comment: @Lix: You're right. I fixed the issue by adding the ```.git``` folder. Thank you for your hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you didn't copy .git folder in your backup. I think the best thing you can do is clone the project from remote and overwrite you backup project files on the files you fetched from remote server. This way you can commit your changes to your project.

Comment: You save my life! The comment comes in handy. Thanks!